# Apiplatform ignores group context

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, symfony6

The apiplatform serializer completely ignores the 'groups' attribute.
Below code:

Controller:

```
$response = $this->serializer->deserialize($params, User::class, 'json');
return $this->json($response);
```

Entity:

```
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['res']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['req']],
)]
class User
{
    #[Groups("req")]
    private string $name = '';
    #[Groups("res")]
    private string $token = '';
}
```

Returns:

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "token": "def1",
}
```

I updated symfony to version 6.4 (and even 7.0) and apiplatform to version 3.2, with no results. I tried using the standard configuration and it also didn't work.

Comment: ApiPlatform shouldn't make use of a controller by default. And if it does, you should not be the one to denormalize the content. Can you provide more of your controller so we can get a better understanding of your context ? You can also update your class attributes, surely, if you're using a controller, then the attribute `controller` is missing in your code example. I would also advise you to try to avoid oversimplified examples, it prevent us from helping you properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not API-Platform that ignores the context, it's you! By implementing a custom controller/action (which is not recommended) you bypass all the included listeners. You explicitly call `serialize` yourself and you don't pass it any context.

To utilize all the APIP listeners, including the serializelistener (which respects the operation contexts) you should remove your custom action and instead implement an eventsubscriber.

If you really want to stick to your custom action, you need to do all the work yourself (e.g. determine the context groups and pass them to the serilizer)